# Criar Ficheiro xlsx com tabela html

Tags: php, odbc, phpexcel, sybase

Boas, estou a tentar passar os valores de uma tabela HTML que recebe dados de uma base de dados SYBASE atravès do odbc.

Ao criar uma formatção de ficheiro 'xlsx' o excel impede que a página criada abra e apresenta o seguinte erro " O excel não pode abrir o seguinte ficheiro porque o formato ou a extensão de arquivo não é válida".

O código usado nesta situação é o seguinte :

```
header("Content-Type:   application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xlsx");  //File name extension was wrong
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

De outro modo, tentei guardar o ficheiro como sendo um .xls e ele dá-me o mesmo erro,embora, ele me permita abrir o ficheiro.

Codigo usado nesta situação :

`header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xls");  //File name extension was wrong
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);`

O problema é que preciso mesmo que o ficheiro criado seja um ficheiro .xlsx e não um .xls.

Já tentei utilizar o PHPExcel para o fazer e, a verdade é que consigo criar uma tabela .xlxs mas a complexidade dos dados que recebo torna um pouco complexo eu estar a criar um ciclo e ter de preencher celula a celula como se tem de fazer no PHPExcel.
Outro problema que encontro aqui é que a primeira linha do resultado que vem da base de dados é ignorada.

O codigo que estava a usar com o PHPExcel é o seguinte:

```
$ano = addslashes( $_SESSION['anop']);
$codigo = addslashes( $_SESSION['codigo']);

$db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);

$query = odbc_exec($db, 'Select * from GP_Vw_Valores_Pagos where Ano='.$ano.' and Codigo='.$codigo.' order by CD');

 $row = odbc_fetch_array($query);


            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $rowCount = 1; 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,'Cd');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,'Descricao');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,'Tipo');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,'Janeiro');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,'Fevereiro');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,'Março');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount,'Abril');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount,'Maio');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,'Junho');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount,'Julho');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount,'Agosto');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$rowCount,'Setembro');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$rowCount,'Outubro');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P'.$rowCount,'Novembro');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q'.$rowCount,'Dezembro');


        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)){ 
            $rowCount++;

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['CD']);
               $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Descricao']);


        } ;

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    ');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Alguem consegue detetar algum erro ou tem alguma solução melhor que estas?

Answer (score 0):

Aumentei a memória com o seguinte código:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
```